# Installed ROS2 Humble but rclpy not found

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, rclpy

I installed ROS2 humble as per the instructions on https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html on Windows 11 WSL2 using Ubuntu 22.04. No issues during installation and everything appears to work well with Gazebo and RViz, but the moment I try to programmatically interact with the system using the rclpy library, I get the following error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclpy._rclpy_pybind11'**

The C extension **'/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_rclpy_pybind11.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'** isn't present on the system.

Tried installing rclpy manually using the instructions found at https://github.com/ros2/rclpy and got the following error:

/home//rclpy_ws/src/rclpy/rclpy/src/rclpy/_rclpy_pybind11.cpp:18:10: fatal error: rcl/service_introspection.h: No such file or directory

I checked the /opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10 directory and there is no site-packages subdirectory.

I tried uninstalling all of ROS2 using sudo apt-get remove ros-* and then reinstalling everything. Issue persists.

**System Details**

- OS: Windows 11 using WSL2
- Linux: Ubuntu 22.04
- Python: 3.11.5 (Tried using Python 3.10; still failed)
- ROS: ROS2 Humble

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem was but I installed a fresh Ubuntu distro and reinstalled everything and it worked. This is fine for my purposes, but I wish I knew what was wrong.